# `std::async` for asynchronous replies in C++

Tags: c++, asynchronous, dbus, stdasync

**Overview** :
I have a client-server implementation, which uses DBus([sdbus-c++](https://github.com/Kistler-Group/sdbus-cpp/blob/master/docs/using-sdbus-c%2B%2B.md)) to send asynchronous requests to a server. Now my server interacts with hardware APIs which behaves synchronously and also takes significant time to generate a reply. So I have a `std::queue` at server, that holds all the asynchronous requests received, and processes them one by one. After processing the server, sends the reply back in the form of callback that was registered for the request sent.

```
#client.h

class Client
{ 
    Client();
    ~Client();

    void sendRequestA() 
    {  
       ... use DBus async call to send request to server
    }

    void sendRequestB() {...}
    
    protected:
    virtual void replyCallbackA(const uint8_t& status) = 0 ; // ... callback invoked by the DBus server   
    virtual void replyCallbackB(const uint8_t& status) = 0 ;
}
```

Ì am facing issues with using `std::async` to test this particular usecase.

```
#test.cpp


//std::future<void> gFuture;

class ClientTest : public Client
{
  ClientTest();
  ~ClientTest();
  
  std::future<void> m_future;

  virtual void replyCallbackA(const uint8_t& status) override
  {
      std::cout<<"replyCallbackA status = "<< status<< "\n";
      m_future.get();
      //gFuture.get();
  }

  virtual void replyCallbackB(const uint8_t& status) override
  {
      std::cout<<"replyCallbackB status = "<< status<< "\n";
      m_future.get();
      //gFuture.get();

  }

}

int main()
{
   ClientTest cTest;
   cTest.m_future = std::async(std::launch::async, &ClientTest::sendRequestA, &cTest);
   cTest.m_future = std::async(std::launch::async, &ClientTest::sendRequestB, &cTest);

   //gFuture = = std::async(std::launch::async, &ClientTest::sendRequestA, &cTest);  -- no change in behavior with use of a global std::future.
}
```

My understanding here was that the `sendRequestA` & `sendRequestB`, would be called and as well the callback functions will be invoked.
However, in this case, the `main` exits immediately after calling the `sendRequestA` & `sendRequestB` and the callback response is not received.

Edit: I have also tried using a global variable for `std::future`, but the behavior was the same.

Could anyone tell where my understanding is at fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::async` returns a future that completes with the return value of the function passed to `std::async`.

The second assignment to the future will block until the call to `sendRequestA` completes (it blocks because of the destructor of the previous `std::future` instance). It does not wait until the reply callback is received (unless you are blocking in `sendRequestA` but that would be strange).

`m_future.get()` in your reply callbacks will block until the future is resolved (`sendRequestA` returns). However, it will have been sent already (because that is the only way you would get a reply) and so the `.get()` call would return immediately.

I think you want to be using something more like `std::promise`. In your reply callback you would call `std::promise::set_value` to resolve the future. Calls to the destructor of the future associated with the `std::promise` or to `std::future::get` will block until `std::promise::set_value` is called (or the promise is destroyed).